# pass query parameter to render in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

In an application a developer written code as

**show.html.slim**

```
= render @driver.trips.order("id DESC"), show_driver: false
```

The application dont have any partials like **_driver.html.erb** in the same resource.

In that page it shows all trips of a driver except driver name attribute.

another code snippet

```
= render Trip.order("id DESC"), show_driver: true
```

Model association is

```
driver has_many :trips

trip belongs_to :driver
```

**Is it possible to pass query as a param to render? and which route it states?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass whatever you want to render, as long as it defines `to_partial_path` or is a collection of such objects. ActiveRecord defines it (this is primarily how it is used).

You mentioned that there is no `_driver` partial, however, what you should be looking for is `trips/_trip`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BroiSatse